# HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to get HashMap store a String and a `ArrayList<String>.`
Basicly what I want is for the first String to be a Name, and the arraylist to contain every country the user have been to.

```
Example:
{Andrew, [USA, China]}
{Lola, [Sweden, Denmark]}
```

The problem I meet is whenever the user puts in a country, the country will be stored under both names:

```
"The HashMap contains: {Andrew=[USA, China, Sweden, Denmark], Lola=[USA, China, Sweden, Denmark]}"

ArrayList<String> namelist = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> archive = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> thearchive = new HashMap<>();

(input.equals("New Country")){
    System.out.println("Name of the Person? ");
    String name = in.nextLine();
    if(namelist.contains(name)){
        System.out.println("Which Country have you visited?");
        String country = in.nextLine();
        if (archive.contains(country)){
            System.out.println("You've already visited this country.");
        }
        else {
            test.add(country);
            thearchive.put(name, country);
            System.out.println("HashMap Contains: " + thearchive);
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("The person does not exist please add first.");
    }
```

Does someone knows why the HashMap is not storing the key/values the way I want too?

Comment: You need to provide the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Usually your problem is due to re-using the same ArrayList for all people, so that all folks share the same Countries, all held by the one single ArrayList. A solution is to create a new ArrayList for each person --  meaning `new ArrayList<String>` needs to be inside some loop where you create your traveler's name String.

So for example, you could change your code to this:

```
ArrayList<String> namelist = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<>();

// ArrayList<String> archive = new ArrayList<>();

HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> arkivet = new HashMap<>();

(input.equals("New Country")){
    System.out.println("Name of the Person? ");
    String name = in.nextLine();

    archive = ArrayList<String>(); // **********
    arkivet.put(name, archive);  // ************

    if(namelist.contains(name)){
        System.out.println("Which Country have you visited?");
        String country = in.nextLine();
        if (archive.contains(country)){
            System.out.println("You've already visited this country.");
        }
        else {
            test.add(country);
            thearchive.put(name, country);
            System.out.println("HashMap Contains: " + thearchive);
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("The person does not exist please add first.");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, will try the code to see where it gets me :)

Comment: What does these two lines of code do? "archive = = ArrayList<String>(); // **********", "arkivet.put(name, archive);  // ************" Because I just get illegal start of expression when running the program on those lines

Comment: @Hablo: typo. This happens because I'm working with code snippets that I can't compile, so I can't have a compiler notify me of when my fat fingers are farking up.

Comment: @Hablo: but regardless, don't copy my code, copy my **ideas**. Re-initialize the ArrayList that holds the country names inside of the loop where you create the traveler.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is nota completed so I can't know what is test an thearchive. But let's create an example:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> list = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> anotherlist = new ArrayList<String>();
anotherlist.add("Brazil");
anotherlist.add("USA");
list.put("Augusto", anotherlist);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: The problem with that is that I need to take name and countries from the user through System.in.